# I am trying to get an output of a replaced string value in a Data frame, but its not changing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to replace a string value from a dataframe and its not changing. Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def answer_one():
    energy = pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls', skip_footer=38,skiprows=17).drop(['Unnamed: 0',
                                                                           'Unnamed: 1'], axis='columns')
    energy = energy.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 2':'Country',
                       'Petajoules':'Energy Supply',
                       'Gigajoules':'Energy Supply per Capita',
                       '%':'% Renewable'})
    energy['Energy Supply'] *=1000000
    energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].replace({'China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region': 
                                                   'Hong Kong', 'United Kingdom of Great Britain and 
                                                    Northern Ireland': 'United Kingdom', 'Republic Of 
                                                    Korea': 'South Korea', 'United States of America': 
                                                   'United States', 'Iran (Islamic Republic of)': 
                                                   'Iran'}) 

    return energy
answer_one()
```

I am getting all the output except that last one, where I am trying to replace the country names in 'Country' column.

Comment: Please, provide a sample of your data

Comment: I am not sure what you asked for. The data was taken from "Load the energy data from the file Energy Indicators.xls, which is a list of indicators of energy supply and renewable electricity production from the United Nations for the year 2013".

Comment: Where can I download those data? Could you copy and paste the first rows of those data in your question, in order to do some tests on them?

Comment: No idea how to download the data from the website, will try my best to provide you here.

Comment: Below is the link address. i hope this helps: https://nruhmiyrfksekvibkfklyq.coursera-apps.org/notebooks/Energy%20Indicators.xls

Comment: @KaiserAzad May be it is because of the indentation it is not working for you. Are you getting any error or is it simply not working?

Comment: @davidbilla i am not getting any error. I am getting the output of above code, but simply the last line code is not giving anything to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any issues with the `.replace()`. Maybe there is something else missing which we are not aware from the hidden dataset. I just created a sample df with the values you got there and replaced them as you have done. 
The df now has the original values for the country column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region',
                   'United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland',
                   'Republic Of Korea',
                   'United States of America',
                   'Iran (Islamic Republic of)'],
                  columns=['Country'])
print(df)
```

Before replace:

```
                                             Country
0     China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region
1  United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern I...
2                                  Republic Of Korea
3                           United States of America
4                         Iran (Islamic Republic of)
```

Used the same `.replace()` and assigned the pairs (see proper indentation)

```
df['Country'] = df['Country'].replace({'China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region': 'Hong Kong',
                                       'United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland': 'United Kingdom',
                                       'Republic Of Korea': 'South Korea',
                                       'United States of America': 'United States',
                                       'Iran (Islamic Republic of)': 'Iran'})
print(df)
```

After replace:

```
          Country
0       Hong Kong
1  United Kingdom
2     South Korea
3   United States
4            Iran
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Appreciate it. :)

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Cheers :)